# Best way to identify a person without using facial recognition (deep learning)

Tags: deep-learning, yolo, resnet, facial-identification

I have a cctv video where I want to identify a person. I tried both facial recognition and object tracking but both failed to produce high accuracy since the quality of the frame isn't great and the face disappears from the frame sometimes.

I have simplified the problem as much as I can and now thinking about training a YOLOV3 on the person and do object tracking or training on Resnet50 as a classification problem.

I have also looked into re-identification but not sure if it will work in this use case or not.

So the problem now is simplified to given an image of people and objects in hostile environment, how do you find and identify specific person?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that *deep learning* is *precisely* the tool to use for identifying a specific person. And *without* facial recognition that seems impossible, unless the person wears the same clothes every time and that's your criteria for "specific person".

Consider using [Face-API.js](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js/) -- you provide several photos of the *specific person* and you can then detect whether they are in a particular image.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still open to use video as input and not a specific frame you can look into person identification through gait.

One example of a deep learning implementation would be:
https://github.com/marian-margeta/gait-recognition